# Python Data Structure Describer module

Tags: python

I'm dealing with trying to find a way to describe a data structure in an easy way.

My goal is to find a module (if its already created to do the following):

Input a Dict/List/Tuple object and you feed the object to the module will iterate through the whole structure and produce a pretty way of stating:

The structure is like this:

```
dict 
[ list
{ sub_dict (x24) etc
list1]
dict1 }
```

Comment: i know this is a weird ask, i'm just trying to discover say "json" data from a website, and when i print it, it shows a large output, and using pprint.pprint() would be great but then i have to scroll through the pages to find "oh thats a dict" ok "edit code" .. then next object etc.... would be cool to find this... i would code it but wondering if someone has already created.

Comment: you're probably looking for [pprint - Data Pretty Printer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)?

Comment: @Jab, looks close, but i'm not looking for the data in the structure, more like the structure of the kinds of objects... more abstract... like "this is a list of dicts" and describes it similar to the pprint stuff..

Comment: You will need to create this